# Remover arquivo de texto

Tags: c, arquivo

Estou tendo problemas para remover um arquivo de texto em C.
Logo depois de usar a função fclose(), utilizo a remove() indicando o nome do arquivo de texto, porém o arquivo não é excluido (a função remove() não está retornando 0);
O que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Qual é o valor do [errno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errno.h) após a chamada ao remove?

Comment: Cole aqui seu código e o respectivo retorno.

Comment: Talvez `perror()` te ajude a perceber o que acontece: `if (remove(filename)) perror(filename);`

Comment: Tente rodar o programa como administrador.

Answer (score 3):

André veja se o código abaixo oferece alguma ajuda.

Como não tinha o código que você usou para verificar eu fiz um e testei aqui.

Vale lembrar o que o Lucas Henrique comentou, certifique-se que seu usuário tem permissão para efetuar essa remoção, no caso abaixo eu mesmo criei o arquivo e apaguei, se você estiver apenas lendo um arquivo existente talvez seu usuário não tenha permissão para remover o arquivo.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h> // inclui apenas para usar o sleep

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    char * file_name;

    file_name = "testeremove";

    printf("Criando arquivo\n");

    fp = fopen(file_name, "w");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("erro ao criar o arquivo para escrita\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Colocando um conteudo no arquivo\n");

        fprintf(fp, "Colocando um conteudo qualquer");
        fclose(fp);

        sleep(10); // aguarda 10 segundos antes de apagar o arquivo, coloquei para você poder checar o arquivo criado
        int ret;
        ret = remove(file_name);
        printf("%d\n",ret);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

Espero ter ajudado.